# info: are there vim controls for the info pages?

Tags: info

```
info foo
```

Next, I am in a `foo` page with links navigated by enter and arrow keys.  Are there vim keymap settings for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are, info has this option:

```
--vi-keys
              use vi-like and less-like key bindings.
```

so your command for `foo` is

```
info --vi-keys foo
```

Comment: my b -- didn't realize I didn't accept this

Comment: The default vi-like bindings are really unsatisfactory, this should be tweaked using an `.infokey` file (`info info infokey` !)

Comment: or simply [use vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704313/272449) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make @Tagwint 's solution more systematic, you may add an alias like this in your .bashrc, .zshrc, or whichever configuration file sourced by your environment:

```
alias info='info --vi-keys'
```